# Why does my Smartphone fire "touchend" too often?

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas

I would like to draw lines on a canvas with my Nexus 4. It works perfectly on my computer, but on my Nexus 4 it skips lines.

You can [try it here](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/).

I think the problem is that the `touchend` event gets fired too often.
Why does this happen?

## Code

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Write Mathematical Formulas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/> <!--320-->
        <style type="text/css">
#myCanvas
{
  border = 1px solid black;
}
#controls
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <canvas id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
    <input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:0; left:0" value="Clear" onclick="clearDr()"/>
    <script src="js/recognition.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
var canvasWidth = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth - 1;
var canvasHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 25;

var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mouseDownEventHandler(e){
  paint = true;
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, false);
    redraw();
  }
}

function touchstartEventHandler(e){
  paint = true;
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop, false);
    redraw();
  }
}

function mouseUpEventHandler(e){
  paint = false;
}


function mouseMoveEventHandler(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
}

function touchMoveEventHandler(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
}

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

function redraw(){
  // Clears the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 

  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 5;

  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}

function clearDr() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
    clickX = new Array();
    clickY = new Array();
    clickDrag = new Array();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownEventHandler);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartEventHandler);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMoveEventHandler);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',touchMoveEventHandler);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEventHandler);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', mouseUpEventHandler);

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (?all?) browsers emulate mouse even when touch is used to ensure compatibility.
Try using stopPropagation and preventDefault on the touch event handler to prevent both handler to trigger. 
Or in fact the 'clean' way to do it is to detect wether you're on a touch or mouse device by starting a 'race'. Once you know the device, just hook the relevant handler.

```
function mouseWins(e) { setUpHandler (  true  , e );  }  
function touchWins(e) { setUpHandler (  false , e); }

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseWins);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchWins);

function removeRaceHandlers() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseWins);
    canvas.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchWins);
}

function setUpHandler(isMouseandNotTouch, detectEvent) {
    removeRaceHandlers();
     if (isMouseandNotTouch) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEventHandler);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMoveEventHandler);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownEventHandler);
        mouseDownEventHandler (detectEvent)
    } else {
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartEventHandler);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',touchMoveEventHandler);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', mouseUpEventHandler);
        touchstartEventHandler (detectEvent)
    }
}
```

Edited : i added the handling of the first detection event.
Could you please preventDefault() / stopPropagation() in your touch handlers, so i can test on my device with no scroll issue ?

Comment: The problem is still there.

Comment: mmm... strange... you are doing your tests with only one finger ? because your code does not handle multi-touch, and your device is multi-touch, so in a first time be sure to touch only one place. Later you'll have to check the touches id to be sure the one ending is the one you were following.

Comment: Yes, I do use only one finger. When I move the finger faster, the strokes get longer. So it seems to me that `endtouch` is fired too often.

Comment: So it might be a Nexus 4 problem ... I'll ask some friends to try it. By the way, with your solution, I need to make an initial click / touch on the canvas, before I can start. Is there a way to start directly?

Comment: Ok, I've just tried it with Firefox on my Nexus 4. It works fine, except that it's slow. With Opera, I get the same problems as with Chrome. So it might be a problem of [`Blink`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine)).

Comment: Ok, your answer "it's a bug" is correct. I've just filed the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344794. Could you please add this link to your answer?